# Vue JS - Display option 2 of select menu after it is disabled

Tags: vue.js

I am looking for help on how to display the second option in a select drop-down menu after the select menu is disabled.

It is disabled if there are fewer than 2 options left. The first option is the 'Please select' option but I would like it to display the one remaining option which is the second option. i.e. 'Scotland' in the code below. The data is pulled in using an Axios call so I do not know what the value will be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Select menu image.]

**The select menu code**

```
 <select disabled="disabled">
    <option disabled="disabled" value="">Select nationality</option>
    <option value="Scotland"> Scotland </option>
    </select>
```

**Vue**

```
   computed: {         
        selectDisabled: function() {
          return this.options.length <= 2;
        }
      }
    });


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app">
      <select v-model="quantity" :disabled="selectDisabled">
        <option disabled value="">Select</option>
        <option v-for="option in options" :value="option">{{option}}</option>
      </select>   
 


   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a special computed property that will dynamically tell the `<select>` which option it should show inside itself. `<select>` show the option that matches the `<select>`'s value.

So:

- When the select is disabled (has less than 2 options) force it's value to be the value of the first listed option (`this.options[0]`).
- When the select is enabled, pass the normal value selected by the user (`this.value`)

I've implemented the logic you need below (make sure to click "Run snippet"):

```js
const App = {
  el: '#app',
  template: `
    
    <div>
      <!-- 
        Remember that writing v-model="quantity" is the same as writing :value="quantity" @input="quantity = $event" 
        (or @input="quanity = $event.target.value" if you put in HTML elements)
        
        You can't use v-model="valueFormatted" here because this would be the same as writing
        :value="valueFormatted" @input="valueFormatted = $event.target.value"
        
        So that's a mistake, because valueFormatted is a computed and you can't assign to it 
        (unless you create a special computed with a setter, but that's not what you need right now)
      -->
      <select :value="valueFormatted" @input="value = $event.target.value" :disabled="disabled">
        <option disabled="disabled" value="">Select nationality</option>
        <option v-for="option in options" :value="option">{{option}}</option>
      </select>
      <hr>
      <div>
        <button @click="options = ['Scotland']">Make the select have 1 item</button>
        <button @click="options = ['Scotland', 'Poland']">Make the seelct have 2 items</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      options: ["Scotland", "Poland"],
      value: '',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    disabled() {
      return this.options.length < 2
    },
    /*
     * If this.disabled is true, returns the value of the first option
     * If it's false, it returns the normal value from data (user selected)
     */
    valueFormatted() {
      //watch out - this computed will return undefined if this.disabled is true and if options is empty
      //to avoid that, you can do for example this:
      //return this.disabled === true ? (this.options[0] ?? '' ) : this.value;
      return this.disabled === true ? this.options[0] : this.value;
    },
  },
}

new Vue(App);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="app" />
</body>

</html>
```

You're probably going to use this select's value later to make eg. an API call, so make sure to send `this.valueFormatted` instead of `this.value`

Comment: Thank you very much!! A great and extremely helpful response.